# Android Activity Invisible by Default

Tags: android, android-activity, visibility

I have an activity defined like this

```
<activity android:name=".queue.ItemDetailActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

This activity implements runnable and shows a progress bar while data is retrieved from the server.  I would like to have the dialog invisible until the data is loaded.  Is there a way for the activity to start invisible and then later use `setVisible(true);` to make it appear?

Comment: Do you mean, that the activity is displayed in this greyed out style in the background while loading?

Comment: I'd like the dialog to not be visible at all until the data is pulled in from the server and loaded into the fields.

Comment: I am confused you want the activity to be invisible? as in in background , so to say , till data is loaded?

Comment: @Ravi - yes.  Right now I have the layout hidden but the title shows.  Then after the data is loaded I change the visibility on the layout and the window expands.  I'd prefer it to not show at all until it's loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Try this style for the activity.

```
<style name="Invisible" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm sure this technique used to work for me, but now it's putting a "dimming" overlay on the rest of the device's UI (as if a dialog is showing in front of it). Any suggestions on how to clear this up?

Comment: I think I've found it. The following style element seems to solve it:
 
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>