# Prevent screen display until after fetching data

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way I can go from one activity to another and delay the display of the screen on the target activity?

What I want to be able to do is to allow the target activity to fetch its required data but not to display anything until does.
I want the screen of the source activity to still be visible until I am ready with the data in the second activity.

Specifically, I am using an AsyncTask to fetch the data.
I know I could fetch the data in the source activity and then send it on to the target activity but this is not viable in our case.

Edit: More Info:

The whole reason I want this is because I am trying to change the structure of certain parts of the current code.
At present the way it works is the the first activity gets the data and then sends it to the second activity as a bundle.
This created problems when the second activity could be invoked from multiple places. It resulted in loads of duplicate code.

So, I decided to move the fetching of the data into the target activity thus cutting out any need for repeating code.

it also makes more sense for the activity to fetch its own data rather than relying on something else sending it.

Comment: Why don't you show a `ProgressDialog` meanwhile its downloading/fetching data?

Comment: That doesn't help because the switching of activity shows an new, empty screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should first make a service that runs your async task. Then, start the service from your first activity with `startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterServiceManager.class));`

When the task ends in the service, start the second activity.

[Click here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) for an excellent service tutorial.

Comment: In some ways this kind of defeats the whole reason. I'll add more in the original post. Surely it would require me to create a service for each target activity.

Comment: You could always have one service, [pass extra data](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/03/pass-data-from-activity-to-service.html) to it corresponding to the task you wish to perform and the activity you wish to call when the task is done. Then in the service, just get the extra variables, run the task, and call the specified activity. It would only be one service.

Comment: I hope that made sense, tell me if it didn't.

Comment: That would bring us back to similar to what we have now. At the moment the "caller" invokes a class that goes and gets the data (in our case from the web) and then it sends control on to a new activity witht he result from the fetch as a bundle. This worked ok but I prefered to change it so that the target activity does all the work. This is expecially true for a tabbed activity. It seemed weird to me that the data for the first tab would come from "outside" whereas the data for the others is created within the activity.

Comment: I tried to create a static method within the target Activity class. It would get the data and then start the activity. Problem is that I ended up with problem of static methods trying to call instance methods. :(

Comment: According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), an activity is a `focused thing that the user can do`, so Activities really aren't made for this type of hidden work. A service really is the best option here, and is the correct way to do things in the context of android programming. If you really want your Activity to be hidden, check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184065/android-activity-invisible-by-default). It's all I could really find.

Comment: So, using that link I managed to keep the target activity hidden. It shows when data is finished. Only problem is that it remains transparent. How do I switch to the default theme. setTheme(android.R.theme) doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14987/discussion-between-theblitz-and-jebego)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use service for this purpose.