# Doing animation on "hidden" Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have been working on trying to get an Activity to not show until data has been selected and is ready for display: [Prevent screen display until after fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827480/prevent-screen-display-until-after-fetching-data)

Finally got it to work with the aid of themes.

Now I have another problem.

I need to animate the transition from one Activity to the next.
I know how to use overridePendingTransition but this won't work here since I am already in the target Activity when I want to do the animation.
The only reason I can see the other one is because the current one is transparent.

I have no problem sliding in the new one:

```
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_screen, null);
    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right));
    setContentView(view);
```

However, I can't think of any way to get the old one to slide out.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Create a "slide out left" animation. Then adjust your animation for the new view, so when the animation starts, you apply and start the other animation to the other view. E.g.,

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.slide_in_right);
    animation.setDuration(TIME);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO - Set and start other animation here
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

view.startAnimation(animation);
```

[Edit]

```
 // First, define and infalte the view that will be incoming
 View upcomingView = inflater.inflate(...);

 // Next, we'll set the animation up
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
        R.anim.slide_in_right);
animation.setDuration(TIME);
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        Animation outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
        R.anim.slide_out_left);
        upcomingView.startAnimation(outAnimation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }
});

currentView.startAnimation(animation); // This will start the animation defined above, which will also set and start the animation for the incoming object
```

Comment: Problem is that that will be applied to the new view. The other view is not even in the current Activity so how do I get a handle on it in order to animate it?

Comment: So you would need to have two separate views defined. One view, we'll call it currentView, needs to have the animation as defined above. This will make it begin to slide out to the right. Then you'll need another view (already inflated), which i'll call upcomingView. In the "onAnimationStart", you need to apply the slide in left animation to, and then call a 'start' for it. I'll update my original post so you can see the code more clearly.